# How to reduce number of bit of integer to 4 and 5 bit from the list in Python 2?

Tags: python

I have list, consist of number from 1 to 15. For example
[[2,4,8,5,7,10,3],[2,15,12,8,4]]

Because it is only 1 to 15, how can I compress the memory by reduce the number of bit of integer become only 4 bit integer for each element?

I also have other similar list that can be represented by 5 bit. So, I want to change it also.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can actually reduce the size an integer takes up in Python, but one quick thing you could do is treat your numbers as part of bitfield that you fit into an int and can check so for your list would reduce to [[0x24857A3], [0x2FC84]] which you can make and recover with the bitmask 0xF and shifting left and right. The five bit would use the same idea,  but the bitmask of 0x1F instead.

Comment: Your comment might be a way. But may be, instead of all of list member in one integer (as this might be impossible for bigger list), I think it is better to group the number to fulfill number of bit in int8 or int16 or int32 or int64 (in numpy array - I think it is possible to convert list to numpy array). For example, for 4 bits, we can group every 2 numbers to create 1 byte (int8 data type). But the problem is in 5 bits. May be, the best way is int16 to group 3 numbers and 1 bit filler.

This is my first time to code python. It needs time to try this. I will let know if I succeed.

Comment: I just remember. For 5 bits, it may be possible to serialize 8 numbers to become 40 bits (or 5 bytes or 5 int8 numbers). I will try. Thank you for the idea @Dom